# how get id with onchange for filtering

Tags: odoo

how can i retrieve the value of a many2one field or its ID from another model
for exemple:

```
class Contrat(models.Model):
_name = 'facturation.contrat'
contrat_parent_id = fields.Many2one('facturation.contrat', string='Numéro Contrat Client',
                              domain=[('is_prestataire', '=', False)])



class Lot(models.Model):
contrat_id = fields.Many2one('facturation.contrat', ondelete='cascade')
articlecontrat_ids = fields.Many2many('facturation.articleouvrage',string='Article Lot')
```

91/5000
i want that when i change contrat_parent_id i get it back to use it and filter my articles for field 'articlecontrat_ids'

Answer (score 2):

here you need to use onchange event i'm assuming that `facturation.articleouvrage` have a m2o field named `contrat_id`

```py
# in onchange event always put the name of the field that trigger the event 
@api.onchange('contrat_parent_id ')
def onchange_contrat(self):
    """update the domain when we change the contrat"""
    if self.contrat_parent_id :
        # always check if the field is not empty
        # return the domain like this but i don't know what you need exactly
        return {'domain': {'articlecontrat_ids ' : [('contrat_id ', '=', self.contrat_parent_id.contract.id)]}}
    else: # remove the domain 
        return {'domain': {'articlecontrat_ids ' : []}}
```

if you want to remove all records when user change the contrat_id  but i think you make the user ungry 
to reselect all this records.

```
    self.articlecontrat_ids = [(5, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: thanks Tchi-Odoo for your help, but I want return domain for articlecontrat_ids when I change contrat_parent_id its this possible thanks

Comment: This is how you return a dynamic domain just adapt the code as you want

Comment: i havent m2o field named contrat_id in facturation.articleouvrage.....???

Comment: i havent m2o field named contrat_id in facturation.articleouvrage.....???class ArticleOuvrage(models.Model):
 _name= 'facturation.articleouvrage'
 _rec_name = 'article_id'

 article_id = fields.Many2one('facturation.article',string='Article',ondelete="cascade")
 ouvrage_id = fields.Many2one('facturation.ouvrage',string="Ouvrage",ondelete="cascade")

Comment: Mr Tchi-Odoo ansewer me please

Comment: did you use onchange to update the domain and what happened.

Comment: check my edits but when you select a contrat_parent_id what the domain should be

Comment: I have two models, where I put this function and how I call it

Comment: put in the model that contains the m2m field and the o2m field  facturation.contratf i think.