# whay slef.id is false with filter domain?

Tags: odoo-8

my filter no work, because sel.id get value false, i don't now where the error?

```py
    def default_domain_users(self):
        at=[]
        userx = self.env.user.login
        if userx == "name.user":
            ids_biens=self.env['gmat.journaleline'].search([('exp_P','=',0),('rapJor_ids','=',self.id)])
            for item in ids_biens:
                    at.append(item.bien_id.id)
        else:
            ids_biens=self.env['gmat.journaleline'].search([('rapJor_ids','=',self.id)])
            for item in ids_biens:
                at.append(item.bien_id.id)
        return [('id','in', at)]

    user_filter = fields.Many2one('gmat.nbien',domain=default_domain_users)
```

Comment: Because the record is not created yet in database, record don't have id yet

Comment: i sorry, but the record exit in database,

Comment: Yes True but when odoo calls the method he call it with empty record set. Like `api.model` did you try onchange ?

Comment: but i use domain, how use onchange  in my code?, domain call function, the model when i call function with domain (nbien) and this code in model in (rapportjournalier)

Comment: take a look at this: onchange is used to change the domain dynamically in the form view:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47123563/how-get-id-with-onchange-for-filtering